# Problems with MPI_Bcast and MPI_Scatter

Tags: c, mpi

I have a problem with implementing this program in `MPI`. I would like to send the data created in process 0 (process Master) to the other processes (process Slave).

In particular I want to send `nCentroids`, `nPointsSlave` and `flag` data via `MPI_Bcast`.

While I want to split the vector of points created in process 0 to other processes via `MPI_Scatter`. Obviously, the divided point vector does not have to be sent to process 0, so process 0 does not have to receive any point vector data, only the Slaves can process the vector data.

Can anyone help me to make everything work properly? I'm really in trouble with this piece of code and don't know how to get out of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank, size;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

MPI_Datatype MPI_PUNTO;
MPI_Datatype type=MPI_DOUBLE;
int blocklen=2;
MPI_Aint disp=0;
MPI_Type_create_struct(1,&blocklen,&disp,&type,&MPI_PUNTO);
MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_PUNTO);


int nCentroids=0;
int nPoints=0;
int nPointsSlave=0;
int flag=0;

Point* points;
Point* buffreceive;

if(rank==0)
{
    int i;
    int nSlave=size-1;
    char *pathInput;

    nCentroids=2;
    nPoints=12;
    flag=1;
    // divide the points between the slaves
    nPointsSlave=nPoints/nSlave;

    pathInput = "/home/rob/eclipse-workspace/Test/in.txt";

    // space allocation for the vector of points
    points=(Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point)*nPoints);

    FILE *input;
    input=fopen(pathInput,"r");

    // load the data present on the file into the points vector
    for(i=0; i<nPoints;i++)
    fscanf(input,"%lf,%lf",&points[i].x,&points[i].y);
    fclose(input);


    buffreceive=(Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point)*nPointsSlave);

    MPI_Bcast(&flag,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nCentroids,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nPointsSlave,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(points, nPointsSlave, MPI_PUNTO, buffreceive, nPointsSlave, MPI_PUNTO, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}else{
    printf("Process %d receive flag: %d\n", rank, flag);
    printf("Process %d receive nCentroids: %d\n", rank, nCentroids);
    printf("Process %d receive nPointsSlave: %d\n",rank, nPointsSlave);

    for(int i=0; i<nPointsSlave; i++)
    {
        printf("Process %d value X %f\n", rank, buffreceive[i].x);
        printf("Process %d value Y %f\n", rank, buffreceive[i].y);
    }
}

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

But the result I get is that all variables are always equal to 0. The for loop to be able to print the points of the vector sent via MPI_Scatter is not read. This is the output my program produces.

```
Process 3 receive flag: 0
Process 3 receive nCentroids: 0
Process 3 receive nPointsSlave: 0
Process 1 receive flag: 0
Process 1 receive nCentroids: 0
Process 1 receive nPointsSlave: 0
Process 2 receive flag: 0
Process 2 receive nCentroids: 0
Process 2 receive nPointsSlave: 0
```

Comment: 1. Don't use the "m-s" terminology. 2. For two numbers you don't need a struct.

Comment: What is "m-s" terminology? 
Should I use a vector to store x and y?

Comment: The "m-s" terminology is what you have called "master - slave".  These days alternatives such as "master - worker" or "director - worker" or some such, are much preferred, at least in the English-speaking parts of the world.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I didn't think about it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you have are:

- `buffreceive` must be allocated in all processes
- `MPI_Bcast` and `MPI_Scatter` must be allocated in all processes

Note that `buffreceive` size must be know *before* allocation, so allocation must occur after `MPI_Bcast`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Datatype MPI_PUNTO;
    // type simplification 
    MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_DOUBLE, &MPI_PUNTO);
    MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_PUNTO);

    int nCentroids=0;
    int nPoints=0;
    int nPointsWorker=0;
    int flag=0;

    Point* points;
    Point* buffreceive;

    if(rank==0)
    {
        int i;
        int nWorkers = size;
        char *pathInput;

        nCentroids=2;
        nPoints=12;
        flag=1;
        // divide the points between the workers
        nPointsWorker=nPoints/nWorkers;

        pathInput = "/home/rob/eclipse-workspace/Test/in.txt";

        // space allocation for the vector of points
        points = malloc(sizeof(Point)*nPoints);

        FILE *input = fopen(pathInput,"r");

        // TODO: test if input is not null

        // load the data present on the file into the points vector
        for(i=0; i<nPoints;i++)
            fscanf(input,"%lf,%lf",&points[i].x,&points[i].y);

        fclose(input);
    }

    // Here, process 0 will behave like all other worker

    MPI_Bcast(&flag,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nCentroids,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nPointsWorker,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // you must wait to know size to allocate before allocating
    buffreceive = malloc(sizeof(Point)*nPointsWorker);

    MPI_Scatter(points, nPointsSlave, MPI_PUNTO, buffreceive, nPointsSlave, MPI_PUNTO, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    printf("Process %d receive flag: %d\n", rank, flag);
    printf("Process %d receive nCentroids: %d\n", rank, nCentroids);
    printf("Process %d receive nPointsSlave: %d\n",rank, nPointsWorker);

    for(int i=0; i<nPointsWorker; i++)
    {
        printf("Process %d value X %f\n", rank, buffreceive[i].x);
        printf("Process %d value Y %f\n", rank, buffreceive[i].y);
    }

    free(buffreceive);
    if (0 == rank) {
        free(points);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you want to have a director not doing the same work as worker, one solution is to send dummy data to worker 0.

**Warning** I assume that the `points` memory will be shared linearely among all the processes, first N data going to process 0, N to 2N data to process 1 and so.

```
        int nWorkers = size - 1; // warning, test that it's not 0
        
        nPointsWorker=nPoints/nWorkers; // the same as before
        
        points = calloc(sizeof(Point),  nPoints * size / nWorkers ); // the trick is here : more room is reserved to send dummy data to process 0

        for(i=0; i<nPoints;i++)
            fscanf(input,"%lf,%lf",&points[i+nPointsWorker].x, &points[i+nPointsWorker].y); // here we don't fill points from 0 ot nPointsWorker : the memory that is sent to process-0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been very kind! Another question, if I don't want to split points even with root process (ID 0), but only between worker processes, should I use MPI_scatterv? So the buffer `points` will only be split between worker processes.

Comment: If the size of the data sending to other processes differs, you need to use MPI_scatterv. For example. Total data size is 10. There are 4 processes. Let's say if you decided scatter the data into [1, 2, 3, 4] four piece. Then you need to use MPI_scatterv

Comment: The size of the data to be sent to all processes is the same. I don't want to though
that the data is received by process 0 because only the workers have to process it. For example, if I have 4 processes and I have 12 points, process 0 must divide them so that 4 points go to process 1, process 2 and process 3.

If I use scatter the 12 points are split between all 4 processes. I don't know if I was able to explain the problem.

Comment: @Roberto I understand your point, I updated my answer accordingly, but I'm not sure that it's the `MPI_Scatter` philosophy. I you want to control which worker get which value, you could use [`MPI_Send`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.1/man3/MPI_Send.3.php)

Comment: Ok, thank's so much

Answer (score 1):

The reason other processes do not receive any data is that the above code did not call  `MPI_Bcast`, and `MPI_Scatter` for other processes relatively.

By convention, you do not need to differentiate these one-to-all mpi commands `MPI_Bcast` and `MPI_Scatter` for ROOT and other processes.

The structure of the code should looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    ... // 

    int nCentroids=0;
    int nPoints=0;
    int nPointsSlave=0;
    int flag=0;

    Point* points = nullptr;
    Point* buffreceive = nullptr;
    
    if(rank==0) {
        ... // calulate size related code here
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&flag,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nCentroids,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nPointsSlave,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank==0) {
       points=(Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point)*nPoints);  // root allocate space for whole data.  
       ... // root then reads date from the file
    }
    buffreceive=(Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point)*nPointsSlave);  // reserver space for other processes
    
    MPI_Scatter(points, nPointsSlave, MPI_PUNTO, buffreceive, nPointsSlave, MPI_PUNTO, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    ... // print the value and etc

    if(rank==0) {
        free(points);
    }
    free(buffreceive);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

---

P.S.
You don't need to worry "ROOT process does not need to scatter, or broadcast date to itself."  As MPI APIs are smart enough to handle this case. They will finish the job without unnecessary cost automatically.

Comment: There are two miscellaneous: 1. if size-related calculation is light weighted and **universal** to all processes, you can calculate them for each process instead of broadcasting them. 2. `malloc-free` is not recommended, Using `stl::vector`, or even `new-delete` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed the code according to your instructions, but there are problems on scatter, maybe the problem is related to the Datatype MPI_PUNTO. 
Maybe the structures have to be managed differently to be split with scatter?

Comment: Could be, I recommend you start with an easy example and make it work. and then gradually add your functions. It would be easier to debug.

Comment: For that MPI_PUNTO. You can use ``` MPI_Datatype MPI_PUNTO;
  MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_DOUBLE, &MPI_PUNTO);
  MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_PUNTO);```

Comment: I updated the solution according to @Mathieu note. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect everything works with your modifications. In case I wanted to insert MPI_Scatter and MPI_Bcast in the root process and have the data sent to the other processes, could this be done?
Then the master sends flags, nCentroids, nPointsWorkers and points and the workers receive the data.
I would like to set everything up this way, but obviously running the program I don't get anything.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank, size;
        
.......//

Point* points;
Point* buffreceive;

if(rank==0)
{
    int i;
    int nWorkers = size-1;

    .......//

    MPI_Bcast(&flag,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nCentroids,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nPointsWorker,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // you must wait to know size to allocate before allocating
    points = calloc(sizeof(Point),  nPoints * size / nWorkers );
    // you must wait to know size to allocate before allocatin
    buffreceive = malloc(sizeof(Point)*nPointsWorker);
    MPI_Scatter(points, nPointsWorker, MPI_PUNTO, buffreceive, nPointsWorker, MPI_PUNTO, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}else
{
    printf("Process %d receive flag: %d\n", rank, flag);
    printf("Process %d receive nCentroids: %d\n", rank, nCentroids);
    printf("Process %d receive nPointsSlave: %d\n",rank, nPointsWorker);

    for(int i=0; i<nPointsWorker; i++)
    {
        printf("Process %d value X %lf\n", rank, buffreceive[i].x);
        printf("Process %d value Y %lf\n", rank, buffreceive[i].y);
    }
}

free(buffreceive);
if (0 == rank) {
    free(points);
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```